# How to implement the expected output using hive

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

1.Table1 and Table2 are related, where table1 px coo combination's time entry is displayed in tabel2. I need the last time entry for each px coo combination. How to implement this using hive ? Expected output is shown below for reference.

```
px1    coo1
px1    coo2
px1    coo3
px2    coo2
px2    coo4
px3    coo3
px4    coo4
```

Table2

```
id1     2014-01-01 21:23:23,273     px1    coo1
id2     2014-01-01 22:01:22,377     px1    coo1
id3     2014-01-01 22:25:06,196     px1    coo1
id4     2014-01-01 22:51:39,487     px1    coo1
id5     2014-01-01 02:05:57,875     px1    coo2
id6     2014-01-01 02:09:42,675     px1    coo2
id7     2014-01-01 23:19:42,059     px1    coo3
id8     2014-01-01 23:34:51,782     px1    coo3
id9     2014-01-01 06:13:05,531     px2    coo2
id10    2014-01-01 06:27:36,676     px2    coo2
id11    2014-01-01 06:59:43,999     px2    coo2
id12    2014-01-01 09:21:57,325     px3    coo3
id13    2014-01-01 17:19:06,956     px4    coo4
id14    2014-01-01 17:27:05,128     px4    coo4
```

The expected output should be

```
id4     2014-01-01 22:51:39,487     px1    coo1
id6     2014-01-01 02:09:42,675     px1    coo2
id8     2014-01-01 23:34:51,782     px1    coo3
id11    2014-01-01 06:59:43,999     px2    coo2
id12    2014-01-01 09:21:57,325     px3    coo3
id14    2014-01-01 17:27:05,128     px4    coo4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table2 ,last columns will be in accordance with table2.( i mean here acting on table 2 itself you can get result as pix_id,coo_id will be in correct match in table2.)  If my assumption is wrong plz excuse.

```
hive (sflow)> desc table2;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
id  string  from deserializer
time_stamp  string  from deserializer
pix_id  string  from deserializer
coo_id  string  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.277 seconds
```

hive(sflow) >

```
SELECT t2.id,t2.time_stamp,t2.pix_id,t2.coo_id
   FROM table2 t2 JOIN
        ( SELECT pix_id,coo_id, Max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp)) as max_epoch 
          FROM table2 
          GROUP BY pix_id,coo_id)  temp   
WHERE t2.pix_id=temp.pix_id AND t2.coo_id=temp.coo_id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp) = max_epoch ;
```

ps:  here by copying the complete log(please note that i am running Pseudo mode hadoop , hive 0.9 , 2GB RAM ) :

```
hive (sflow)> from table2 t2 join (select pix_id,coo_id, Max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp)) as max_epoch from table2 group by pix_id,coo_id) temp
            > select t2.id,t2.time_stamp,t2.pix_id,t2.coo_id where t2.pix_id=temp.pix_id and t2.coo_id=temp.coo_id and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp) = max_epoch ;

Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 24 seconds 0 msec
OK
id  time_stamp  pix_id  coo_id
id4 2014-01-01 22:51:39,487 px1 coo1
id6 2014-01-01 02:09:42,675 px1 coo2
id8 2014-01-01 23:34:51,782 px1 coo3
id11    2014-01-01 06:59:43,999 px2 coo2
id12    2014-01-01 09:21:57,325 px3 coo3
id14    2014-01-01 17:27:05,128 px4 coo4
Time taken: 145.17 seconds

hive (sflow)> 
hive (sflow)> desc table2;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
id  string  from deserializer
time_stamp  string  from deserializer
pix_id  string  from deserializer
coo_id  string  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.277 seconds
hive (sflow)>
```

Comment: i am new bee to stackoverflow. please excuse if any formatting issues in answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `collect_max` UDF from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) to generate the data with only one job step.

```
select array_index( map_keys( max_map ), 0) as id,
    from_unixtime( array_index( map_values( max_map), 0) as time_stamp,
    pix_id,
    coo_id
from (
   select pix_id, coo_id, 
       collect_max( id, unix_timestamp(time_stamp) ) as max_map
   from table2
   group by pix_id, coo_id ) cm ;
```

For small datasets, it doesn't really matter, but for very large datasets, it allows you to solve your problem with only one pass of the data.

Comment: Jerome Banks Got this error --> FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 2:9 Function Argument Type Mismatch from_unixtime: Looking for UDF "from_unixtime" with parameters [class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable]